# Is there a way to send params to an observer?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, illuminate-container

Is there a way to send parameters to an Observer in Eloquent ORM?

Based on laravel's documentation:

```
User::observe(UserObserver::class);
```

`observe` method receive a class, not an instance of an object. So I cant do something like:

```
$observer = new MyComplexUserObserver($serviceA, $serviceB)
User::observe($observer);
```

So, in my code I can do something like:

```
class MyComplexUserObserver
{
    private $serviceA;
    private $serviceB;

    public function __constructor($serviceA, $serviceB){
        $this->serviceA = $serviceA;
        $this->serviceB = $serviceB;
    }

    public function created(User $user)
    {
        //Use parameters and services here, for example:
        $this->serviceA->sendEmail($user);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to pass parameters or services to a model observer?

> Im not using `laravel` directly, but i'm using eloquent (`illuminate/database` and `illuminate/events`)
>
> Im not trying to send additional parameters to an explicit event like in: [Laravel Observers - Any way to pass additional arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923958/laravel-observers-any-way-to-pass-additional-arguments), i'm trying to construct an observer with additional parameters.

---

## FULL SOLUTION:

Thank you to @martin-henriksen.

```
use Illuminate\Container\Container as IlluminateContainer;

$illuminateContainer = new IlluminateContainer();
$illuminateContainer->bind(UserObserver::class, function () use ($container) {
    //$container is my project container
    return new UserObserver($container->serviceA, $container->serviceB);
});
$dispatcher = new Dispatcher($illuminateContainer);

Model::setEventDispatcher($dispatcher); //Set eventDispatcher for all models (All models extends this base model)
User::observe(UserObserver::class);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Observers - Any way to pass additional arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923958/laravel-observers-any-way-to-pass-additional-arguments)

Comment: I don't understand the solution. Where do I put that code? In model, in Event file or in AppServiceProvider? I tried addint that to AppServiceProvider and got an error "Cannot instantiate interface Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher"

Comment: I used `use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher`. Worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Illuminate events there is the [line](https://github.com/illuminate/events/blob/7b8fb06b847a9efac022df4ea63cf6c82749363c/Dispatcher.php#L385), this indicates on event subscription it utilities the container. This mean we can use this to our advantage, i'm not super familiar with non `Laravel` bootstrapped applications. But where ever your app is defined, you will bind your class to your own class.

```
$container = new Container();

$container->bind(MyComplexUserObserver::class, function ($app) {
    return new MyComplexUserObserver($serviceA, $serviceB, $theAnswerToLife);
});

$dispatcher = new Dispatcher($container);
```

This will result in, next time your application resolves your class, it will use this version of it and therefor you can setup your class as you intend.

Edit: an example how you can utilize the `Laravel` container, to utilize the bind functionality.

Comment: It seems the `bind` method is part of the `illuminate/container`, used in laravel but  im not using it... any other possible solution?

Comment: Here is an example of someone utilising the app outside of laravel, i think you are using it, because it needs it for the container which events uses. https://github.com/mattstauffer/Torch/blob/e2cc707b4c73eb1e499558333fb6dc0c2af00cbd/other-components/html/index.php#L23

Comment: I updated the answers with how i think you can solve it

Comment: Thank you! It worked :) (I have updated my question with full solution)